# iphone Audio Book Reader

Tags: iphone, mediaplayer, audiobook

I am using my iPhone to listen to audio books. When the iPhone stays on, I can stop listenting and when I restart it remembers which file I was last listening to, and where in that file I was. However, whenever I turn off the iPhone, it forgets where in an audio file I stopped listening; I have to manually fast forward to where I was.

Is there a way to get the media player to remember where in a file I was when turning off the iphone, or is there a different player software that could do that for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a setting in iTunes to remember position…

Select all chapters, or books etc.
Get Info  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>   > Options tab.

[image]

Comment: That is impressive 4 minutes to replay with customized screenshot. How many fingers do you have?

Comment: the regular 10, though my typing style only uses about 4 of those ;-)

Comment: well, you are way more developed, I can only handle 2 at the time.

Comment: Thanks! This sort of works... now when restarting in the midst of a previous file the media player does remember the position. However, it does not remember which file I was listening to (it used to). I am listening to audio files that I ripped, and they show up as "Music". I tried to set as audiobooks but the media player goes nuts and just keeps cycling between files without actually playing them.

Comment: you should be able to set them as audiobook in iTunes - that's how I got the HHGTTG in there, ripped CD, manually changed type. Works just fine.

Comment: Did you set "remember playback position" before or after setting as audiobook? Second last post at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5345505?start=30 says to do so, and I did as well... but I tried a few times, and every time, media player on iphone goes nuts, just quickly cycling between all the files from a single (original) dvd.

Comment: tbh I don't recall which order i did things in.

Comment: a late thought - you don't have 'shake to shuffle' enabled, do you? That would mess things up if you were jogging ;-)