# Music not starting from last played position

Tags: iphone, podcasts, music.app, podcasts.app

I use the default Music app of my IPhone to listen to podcasts. I want the podcasts to restart where I left them. Sometimes it does, but sometimes it restart at the beginning of the song, which is very annoying. Is there something that explains this behaviour ? When does a song restart from start, and when does it restart from the last played position ? If a consistent behaviour is impossible to achieve in the default app, which app would you recommend ? I just need that feature, I do not need a fully featured podcatcher, because I download the podcasts from my PC then transfer them to the IPhone.

I have an iPhone 4S with iOS 8.3.

Comment: You say podcasts and then song - these are different (and I am not surprised by the difference between behaviour of a podcast and a song) which one is it and which app are you using.

Comment: try http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/181999/85275

Comment: I download the podcasts using RSSOwl on my computer, then transfer them through iTunes as songs to the iPhone. The iPhone does not consider them as podcasts, but as some random mp3, not considering the actual content. I then use the standard music app of the iPhone. The podcast app is not convenient for me as I want to download the podcasts from the computer.

Comment: I think VLC has the good behaviour for me. It seems to reopen from last played position and convenient for my usage. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: Avoid opening your audiobooks off of playlists and use the "Apple generated view" of audiobooks.